# How to use AppWeb To upload files

Tags: c

Anyone knows how to use AppWeb to upload file to server without using ESP?

I used the UploadFilter to do this with C but it didn’t work.

I have already tried lots of methods to handle this but still cannot find the upload files in the UploadDir dictionary.

Very Appreciate for your answers!

Comment: Can you share your `C` code, and errors you encountered?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.